# UnstructuredURLLoader is not avalaible in langchain in javascript

Tags: javascript, streamlit, langchain, py-langchain, langchain-js

Due to this issue I have to use cherrio, html-to-text which is given in documentation , there are some cons of this. When I asked RetrivalQA then It return css properties, URLs and javascript as well , because they are involved init.

Can please some one suggest what is the alternate of ### UnstructuredURLLoader in javascript langchain Please .****